# Can you use another material as input to material nodes in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

Is it possible in cycles to use setup a material node to take the output from another material as input into a mix shader?  This way if I change the configuration in the other material it updates both materials?  Or do I need to do this another way?

I'm surprised nobody has asked this already and can't find anything online so maybe it's not possible.

Comment: Ah yes that works and is different from what I thought a node group was for.  Didn't realize it created an output that was available in different materials. Thanks.  Did you want to create an answer for this or should I?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's a typical use case for [Node Groups](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/controls/nodes/groups.html).

Select all relevant nodes and group them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>. This way the created group is accessible within all material node trees, located in the *Add menu*: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Groups > Your Group Name*.