# How can I get shader node values from one material to another?

Tags: materials, node-editor, objects, shaders

I have a material that generates a height map and applies it to the displacement.

Now I want to make another object, with another material, but I want to use that height data from the first object, in this objects material shader. Is that possible?

Comment: You can create a node group: [Can you use another material as input to material nodes in cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108368/can-you-use-another-material-as-input-to-material-nodes-in-cycles/108374#108374)

Comment: or Ctrl + C and Ctrl + V?